# Adding Xbox Fortnite account to Switch

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

I have an Xbox that I mainly play on. The Xbox has its own Epic account e-mail/login. I also have a Switch, which I sometimes play Fortnite on as well (for mobile purposes); the Switch also has its own Epic account/login.

Long story short, I no longer care for my current Fortnite account on my Switch, and want to use my Xbox account (with all my progress) on my Switch.

Like I said they both have different Epic usernames and passwords which I know, remember and have full access to.

If I unlink my Switch account (I’m aware I’ll lose all data) can I just sign in using my Xbox Epic account and all of my data will be transferred to the Switch?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Its not that simple, However, Epic games are soon releasing a Merging tool linked here.
https://www.epicgames.com/fortnite/en-US/news/account-merge-delay
This will be used to merge both of your accounts for switching consoles.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to create a new switch account and link your Xbox account to that account. Then whenever you want to  play on switch with your Xbox account , just launch fortnite with your new account .This way , you can play on switch with your Xbox account while still having your switch account .

Answer (score 0):

I remember that I had my xbox account and transferred it to Switch just by putting in the same login. You can try that on your xbox but with your Switch it wont wipe it.